# getRange : Cannot convert Nan to Class

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I tried **parseInt** but i really don't know where is the right place to put it in the code :

Here's the code :

```
function projectTime(QuelProjet) {
    var tabUsers = getUsersList();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ProjectSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Liste Projets");
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        //Nombre de jours du mois
        var date = new Date(i + "/01/" + year);
        var numProjects = getProjectNumber();
        var currentMonthSheet = getSheetByMonth(tabMonth[i - 1]);
        for (l = 0; l < tabUsers.length; l++) {
            var firstLine = 1 + (l + 1) * 10 - 10 + (l + 1) * numProjects - numProjects;
            Logger.log("Fline " + l + " : " + firstLine);

            var QuelPro = parseInt(QuelProjet);
            Logger.log("Quelpro : " + QuelPro);

            var nbDays = getNbJours(date);

            var sommeproject = 0;
            var som1 = new Array(1000);
            for (k = 1; k < nbDays + 1; k++) {
                var Row = parseInt(firstLine + QuelPro);

                Logger.log("Row  : " + Row + " QuelProjet : " + QuelPro);
                var Column = k + 1;
                Logger.log("Column : " + Column);
                var range = currentMonthSheet.getRange(Row, Column);
                som1[k] = range.getValues();
                //sommeproject = sommeproject + currentMonthSheet.getRange(firstLine + QuelProjet, k + 1).getValues();
            }
        }
    }
    var sommeproject = 1;
    sommeproject = sommeproject + som1;
    return sommeproject;
}
```

The problem is in this line :

```
var range = currentMonthSheet.getRange(Row, Column);
```

**QuelProjet** is a argument that I put like an integer in the function* when i call it in the spreadsheet

Thanks for your time

Comment: what does `getProjectNumber()` return?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that cannot convert NaN to class, it means that either variable Row or Column or both are not integers. Your issue comes from Row not being an integer.

Since I don't know what getProjectNumber(), I can't fully debug, but this methodology should let you debug.

Use: Logger.log(typeof(variable_name)) so that you can pinpoint where the issue is.
Log the types of the following variables after defining them: numProjects, firstLine, quelPro, and row. 
the logger should log 'number' each time. When it doesn't you've found your error.

If all results are 'number' it's possible that your numbers are not whoel numbers since I don't know what getProjectNumber() returns, and the getRange() function needs whole numbers